# Rmarkdown, Rstudio: pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to render a pdf document with the knit pdf button in RStudio, but I keep on getting this error:

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.167 

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

I know there is a lot be found on the internet regarding error 43, but non of them helped me.
Does anyone know what it means exactly and where I can find the solution? It's peculiar because a few hours ago I had the same error but the rendering went well after adding this in my code:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

But now the error is back

*EDIT*

when trying a minimal example:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r results="asis"}
library(stargazer)
c1 <- c("test1","test1","test2","test2")
c2 <- c(1,2,3,4)
data_object <- as.data.frame(cbind(c1,c2))
names(data_object) <- c("test","test2")
stargazer(data_object,summary=FALSE,rownames=FALSE,type="html")
```
````

The error it gives is:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ec-lmr10): Font ec-lmr10 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Trying to make PK font ec-lmr10 at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The ec-lmr source file could not be found.
miktex-makepk: The application file ttf2pk.exe could not be found.

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

This is a different error, but still a 43 one. I checked it, but the font ec-lmr10 file is on the system. Somehow it can't  be found.

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is a font related one. When you knit a PDF, knitr uses LaTeX and you have to know that "fonts" of LaTeX are not like the standard ones.

To solve your problem try to add the latin model font family by loading the package (at the very top):

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

For more detailed informations about how and where insert this piece of code in your document, have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown).

This package allows you to have scalable fonts; not all fonts of all (font) packages are to so.
I think, but I might be wrong, because first versions of TeX and LaTeX were designed to work with METAFONT.

### Edit

Your code works well for me, it does not produce any error. My idea is that happens because I have a complete Tex live distribution on my Mac (MacTeX). At this point I suppose that the problem relies on some packages that the r packages you use (like `stargazer`) use and you (we) do not know and won't (unless we analyze the code of course).

At this point my suggestion is to download a complete TeX distribution so you will be sure that any error related to PDF output is no related to the underlying tool that Studio uses to produce such PDFs (say, LaTeX).

You can find a complete LaTeX distribution for [Mac](https://tug.org/mactex/) and for [Windows](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Unfortenatly it didn't help

Comment: @user1983395 post a little piece of your code that replicate the error.

Comment: I will, but I think I have change my question as well, because when I try a dummy .rmd file rendering pdf is still giving errors 43 but the exact cause seems different.

Comment: I added an example, but the error is different now. I think the error are caused by RStudio not being able to find the files

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Unfortenately I don't have administrator rights on this machine, so I can't try it right a way. I still think it has something to do with the fact that I am not able to tell rstudio where the tex  files are. They surely are there

Comment: @user1983395 Oh bad times for you. I do hope another power user will provide an useful answer. It is not an easy task.

Comment: A complete distribution did not solve my problem. I checked if I could find the file 'ec-lmr10' font somewhere, and it happened to be in the miktex directories. So it remains strange that RStudio can't find it.