# how to tell RStudio where miktex files are located needed for generating pdf from rmardown?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, rstudio, r-markdown, miktex

I am struggeling to make rendering pdf's from within RStudio possible. I keep on getting 43's errors. There are several topics on stackoverflow regarding this type of error. None of them have helped me. I am pretty sure that RStudio in my case doesn't know where to look for the tex files in MikTeX.

I used the solution mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231595/rstudio-cant-find-pdflatex-on-windows-7).

It gives this piece of code as a solution:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\RMathew\\PortableApps\\MikTeX\\miktex\\bin", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

In my particular case I changed the code to (because that's where it seems to be located on my machine):

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "C:\\Program Files\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64", sep=.Platform$path.sep))
```

With no success. I got the same errors as the errors I get without running that code before rendering the pdf_document.

Does anyone have an idea about what I am doing wrong en how to solve this issue?

Comment: Just checking that `Sys.getenv("PATH")` displays that MikTeX path has been added correctly. Do you by any chance have different MikTeX installations (in your PATH)?

Comment: @Molx, the errors can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180152/rmarkdown-rstudio-pandoc-exe-error-producing-pdf-from-tex-source

Comment: @Roman Luštrik no there isn't. But your question made me wondering if there are MikTeX like files located somewhere else. I will dig deeper into this.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik do you think files like these can cause the problem? C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.1\share\texmf\tex\latex

Comment: What OS are you using ? If you changed to “El Capitan” recently the symbolic link to the active TEX Distribution, /usr/texbin, is removed and can not for security reason be installed there anymore. Therefore you have to adjust the “PATH” variable or install the latest distribution which takes care of this issue. [More information](https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf)

Comment: There is no indication that you have yet addressed the answer you got to a more complete question.

Comment: @BondedDust I guess you are right. I was hoping People would recognize the problem better if i used this approach